# css text-align at 30%

Tags: html, css, text-align

I am looking for an option to align text at a certain percentage of the width.
It would be a div where the text isn't aligned in the center or to the left. It need to be in between.
I'm not shure if there is an easy way of doing so but her is an example to explain it better.
The width of the div is constant but the text changes.
Short text should be alinged underneath the line but when the text gets larger it just expands like it would normaly do when its centered until ther is only space on the right side. Then it behaves like normal left aligned text.

It would be nice if something like this was possible:
`text-align:30%;`
[example with long text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sll1T.png)

Update:
[example, very short text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ipgo.png)

Comment: What about simply using padding-left:30% ?

Comment: You missed to simply explain to what rules obeys the little green line... Is it fixed at left NN, is is's left variable.... how you expect to get a proper answer without showing the minimal code to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to use padding left?

```
.text-to-align {
    padding-left: 30%;
}
```

Here is a working jsfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/umw5mrde/1/

---

UPDATE: Question was updated and here is modified answer to match it:
I found no way to do it with pure css, but there is a solution using javascript with jquery. It substract 30% of a label width from 30% of a parent width. This value is assigned to the left padding of a label.

```
$(".text-to-align").each(function(index) {
    var padding = ($(this).parent().width() - ($(this).width())) * 0.3  + "px";
    // alert(padding);
    $(this).css("padding-left", padding);
});
```

Working jsfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/umw5mrde/2/

But you should definitely avoid it. When your design is so complicated that it requires javascript, change it.

Comment: but if the text is very short than it isn't aligned under the line

Comment: @kobey I updated the jsfiddle. It looks like the situation in the question now.

Comment: I'm sorry i've uploaded the wrong picture for the short example. :/

Comment: @kobey I updated the answer to match your changes.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I was hoping there was a css-only way but this is good enough.